# Teradata Query optimization - INDEX and COLLECT STATISTICS

Tags: sql, query-optimization, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm trying to create a SPROC and I am running into a spool space issue. My IT has confirmed I'm at max.

I can see where my query fails - it is at a place where I am trying to grab over 10m rows of data and do some various case statements, etc. then insert them into a separate table. Apologies for the anonymity but I can't show the real column headers.

How can I use INDEX or COLLECT STATISTICS after an INSERT INTO XYZ.Table statement to optimize this query?

```
INSERT INTO XYZ.TableFinal
SEL 
b.Column1,
b.Column2,
b.Column3,
b.Column4,
b.Column5,
b.Column6,
CASE WHEN b.Column7 = 'A' THEN 'A1'
    WHEN b.Column7  = 'B' THEN 'B1'
    WHEN b.Column7 = 'C' THEN 'C1'
ELSE NULL end AS Column7,
b.Column8,
CASE WHEN b.Column9 = 'AA' THEN 100
          WHEN b.Column9 = 'BB' THEN 200
          WHEN b.Column9 = 'CC' THEN 300
          ELSE 400 end AS Column9,
a.Column10
FROM Table1 a -----This table has millions upon millions of rows
JOIN Table2 b
ON a.Column1 = b.Column1
AND a.Column2 = b.Column2
AND a.Column3 = b.Column3
WHERE  Column3>0 AND Column2 > 0 ----This helps narrow it down a bit, but I still need to pull and analyze 10m+ rows before aggregating them in the following queries.
;
```

I attempted to create an index prior to the select along with collecting stats on the tables, but did not have any success.

Comment: 1, You can get recommended statistics for your select. 2. Find out what the PI is for the target table, make sure your insert isn't causing skew.

Comment: Two thoughts: 1. Turn your temp table into a CTE to use temp space instead of spool space;  `With temptable As (Select b.Column1, etc.`  and 2. If an EXPLAIN of your query shows join before filter, turn table1 and table2 into subqueries that pre-filter column2 and column3 conditions, then join those two to reduce temp usage.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer, I'm trying the CTE option right now but struggling with a few errors. current syntax is: ;with temptable as (select b.Column1, etc.) INSERT INTO FinalTable1 SELECT * from temptable........ I am getting an error with this syntax. I've also implemented your second recommendation. Thank you for that.

Comment: CTE uses spool not temp space, but if you want to try it the WITH goes before the SELECT clause not before the INSERT. I don't fully understand your question. Are you trying to optimize the above INSERT/SELECT or "whatever comes next" in the SP or the entire process end-to-end? (The comment in the SQL mentions aggregation.)

Comment: A Secondary Index will not improve join performance. What's the PI of the target table and the PKs of both tables, is it actually a 1-many-join?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say forget inserting to a table entirely.  Run it all through nested queries and eliminate as many rows as early in the process as possible.

Comment: @Fred I am trying to optimize the insert/select above. The remainder of the query runs fine. The problem is the above query is trying to join and pull back a MASSIVE amount of data (10m+ rows).

Comment: Similar to @ChrisMaurer I was asking indirectly if you really need the intermediate table or if this is part of a larger process that can perhaps be done more efficiently overall. If you do require the intermediate table, what is the Primary Index of the target table and the two source tables? Do the source tables have any secondary / join indexes?

Comment: @Fred, this is done as a part of a larger process. I will try to see if I can find a way to post the entire SPROC here for help.